# How to customize Background for the selected TabItem in Android TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement the tablayout as the following design-
[image: Expected_design]

I could design as this-

[image: Designed_tablayout]

Could anyone please help me to achieve the following points?

1. When a tab is selected, the background should fill the 1st half or the 2nd half of the tab.
2. For a selected tab item, there is a small margin for the background. It should not completely fill the tab.

Code:
MainActvity.xml

```
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="440sp"
            android:layout_height="64sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/backGroundWithWhiteBorder"
            style="@style/customTabLayout"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector" />
```

tab_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/tiffany_blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

backGroundWithWhiteBorder.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="376dp"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:viewportWidth="376"
    android:viewportHeight="64">
  <path
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillColor="#00000000"
      android:strokeColor="#fff"/>
</vector>
```

Style.xml

```
    <style name="customTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabText</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TabText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of `TabLayout` with a `MaterialCardView` as the parent and the `TabLayout` as the child of it. To draw the outer rectangle section you can simply use the properties `app:strokeWidth` and `app:strokeColor` to draw the border and you can move the `TabLayout` inside the `MaterialCardView` using the `android:layout_margin` property.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tabs_selector"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabTextAppearance">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favourites" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

where `@drawable/tabs_selector` is the drawable tabBackground selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#5F9EA0" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and `@style/CustomTabTextAppearance` is used to set a custom Tab Text Appearance:

```
<style name="CustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image: all_tab_selected]

[image: favourites_tab_selected]

Comment: I don't need swipe while switching between the fragments. So instead of using TabLayout and ViewPager, how can we use segmented buttons to implement this? Could you please help to understand the design in that case?

Comment: @Dev_Cob you can simply disable the swipe in ViewPager and switch to the appropriate fragment programmatically on the tab click event. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s) there are a lot of good answers of how to disable the swipe effect.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Basically I want to use SegmentedButtons to reduce the load to the system. Could you please help to design that?

Please check this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088260/how-to-use-segmented-buttons-to-switch-between-fragments

Comment: @Dev_Cob check my answer in that post. Thank you.