# How to use Segmented Buttons to switch between fragments?

Tags: android, android-button

I need to get the following design.

- I need a way without using TabLayout/ViewPager.
- There is no swipe required while switching in between the fragments.

Could you please help to understand how this can be designed with Segmented Buttons?

[image: SegmentedButtons]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
In your layout.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
    />
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
    />
    <Button
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
    />
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

In code:

```kotlin
toggleButton.addOnButtonCheckedListener { toggleButton, checkedId, isChecked ->
    // Respond to button selection
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button

Comment: Thanks!! Could you please let me know how we can set a custom rectangular background with padding for the selected button? Please check the screenshot attached.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the outer/border section you can simply use a `MaterialCardView` as the parent by using the properties `app:strokeWidth` and `app:strokeColor` and add the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` as a child of it. The `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` has the property `app:singleSelection="true"` to act as a single selection and the property `app:selectionRequired="true"` to disable the deselection effect.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:checkedButton="@id/button1">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="All"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Favourites"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

where `style="@style/MyButtonStyle"` is a custom style for each `MaterialButton` like the below:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_background_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

From above the `@color/button_background_color_selector` is the tab background color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#5F9EA0" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

and the `@color/button_text_color_selector` is the tab text color selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

**Result:**

[image: all]

[image: favourites]

**For Custom Tab background Image:**

In case you have a custom background Image for the `MaterialButton` you can't use anymore the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` because it will throw an error like this:

> "Attempted to get ShapeAppearanceModel from a MaterialButton which has
> an overwritten background"

A simple solution is to replace the current `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with a `LinearLayout` something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="All"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Favourites"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetLeft="0dp"
                android:insetRight="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

where `style="@style/MyButtonStyle"` now is the below:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background_drawable_selector</item>
    <item name="android:checkable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

From the above you can use the property `android:background` to add a custom background drawable selector. In our case the `@drawable/button_background_drawable_selector` is defined under the `drawable` folder like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

And programmatically you have to handle which button is now selected by using the `setChecked()` method like the below:

```
MaterialButton button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
MaterialButton button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.setChecked(true);
        button2.setChecked(false);
    }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button2.setChecked(true);
        button1.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I have a drawable image to use as a background for the selected button. When I try as below, it is not working, it is showing the default pink background. Could you please help to set a custom image as the background?


button_background_color_selector.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gen_btn_n" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>

Comment: @Dev_Cob check updated answer for the custom image background in the button.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I am trying this. Could you please let me know in this implementation which one would be better to use- MaterialButton or AppCompatToggleButton ?

Comment: @Dev_Cob The AppCompatToggleButton is preferred in cases you handle things like on/off states, it acts as a switch mode. On the other side the MaterialButton its the default android button which has more options of customization. Check also the answer of "Nguyễn Quang Thọ" in case it suits better in your case which uses the AppCompatToggleButton.

Comment: Thank you! I have used AppCompatToggleButton. Could you please help me to solve another problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099007/how-to-resolve-the-overlapping-of-fragments-with-toggle-buttons

Answer (score 0):

if material button cannot apply gradient background color, so you can use AppCompatToggleButton:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:textOff="App"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOn="App" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="favorite"
        android:textOn="favorite" />
</LinearLayout>
```

button_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_button_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_button_background"/>
</selector>
```

gradient_button_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#00FF00"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

default_button_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#002196F3" />
</shape>
```

[image: toogle button with gradient background]