# Pass only the tap gesture in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, motionevent

I want to implement a non-scrollable `ViewPager`. [People say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/disable-viewpager) that I should override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` functions:

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Okay, I can't swipe now. But I need the taps that are gone too! Both of them are `MotionEvents` with `action=ACTION_DOWN`, so how can I differentiate one from another and pass only taps in this case?

P. S. What the hell? In iOS I can disable scrolling by unchecking one checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that sweep is a continuous touch gesture that starts with `ACTION_DOWN` and ends with `ACTION_UP`. So I can pass touch only with `action=ACTION_DOWN`

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
```