# Disable view pager sliding and make it slide on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am making page signup page that contains page indicator and make it slid-able on button click.I am using view pager to show different fragments.Thus i am using view pager it slide-able on page swipe.I want to stop it and make it slide-able on button click.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
   ViewPager pager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
    {  

    });
    pager.setAdapter(new IntroPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    CirPageIndicator indicator = (CirPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    indicator.setViewPager(pager);

}

public class IntroPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{

    public IntroPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return 5; }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return ""; }
}
```

}

And XML file for this code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F4F4F4">

<view
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

<view
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.dacer.cirpageindicator.CirPageIndicator"
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

can some one help me out .
its important.
thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable scrolling on a ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/is-it-possible-to-disable-scrolling-on-a-viewpager)