# How to disable or enable viewpager swiping in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**What i am trying to do:** I am trying to Enable/disable swiping in pager programatically when the program is running

***Ex:*** When on the flow if i check for a condition and if it returns `true` enable swiping, and if condition returns `false` disable swiping.

---

### [Solution i am using is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/1083093)

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
} }
```

Then select this instead of the builtin viewpager in XML

```
<mypackage.CustomViewPager 
android:id="@+id/myViewPager" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

You just need to call the "setPagingEnabled" method with "false" and users won't be able to swipe to paginate.

---

**Problem with above methodology:** i cannot set the property on the flow, I:e .... I either can enable swiping or disable swiping. But i cannot do this based on condition

---

### Question:

1. Can i achieve my goal in some-other way, if so what is it ?
2. Or is this not possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Comment: Would not it be possible to set the property on the flow with DataBinding ?

Comment: Try to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/42687397/4559365

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Disable swipe progmatically by-**

```
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.Pager); 
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        { 
           return true; 
        }
     });
```

and use this to swipe manually

```
touchView.setCurrentItem(int index);
```

Comment: This still lets the viewpager to be partially swiped (like 1%) before it stops.  It looks ugly.

Comment: His solution works, it is just incomplete. You should also override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) too. This will give you the look you desire without the 1%

Comment: Unable to overide that method

Comment: it works but when it enabled , swiping is very bad and slow

Comment: It not works, try to swipe your view pager repeatedly, and you can see your another view shown !!. you have to set onInterceptTouchEvent too.

Comment: this is absulutally wrong solution, why so many stars. It indeed looks ugly, with swipe of 1%. Probably, we should extend viewpager, and override onInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: If you override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` (return true, for example), the views inside ViewPager will not receive input. Which is __not__ what you want in most cases.

Answer (score 82):

Best solution for me. 
-First, you create a class like this:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
  private Boolean disable = false;
  public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }
  public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context,attrs);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     return !disable && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     return !disable && super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  public void disableScroll(Boolean disable){
      //When disable = true not work the scroll and when disble = false work the scroll
      this.disable = disable;
  }
}
```

-Then change this in your layout:`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
for this`<com.mypackage.CustomViewPager`

-Finally, you can disable it:`view_pager.disableScroll(true);`
or enable it: `view_pager.disableScroll(false);`

I hope that this help you :)

Comment: Thanx Alberto :)

Comment: Also don't forget to call **viewPager.invalidate()** method after calling disable scrolling method, because of that it instantly disable swipe over.

Comment: With this solution the views inside ViewPager will not receive any input if `disable == true`. Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is not the correct solution.

Comment: instead of Boolean I'd rather use boolean here.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to improve a working feature.

Comment: For Viewpager2 you don't need custom class you can simply disable scroll by using
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);

Answer (score 22):

In your custom view pager adapter, override those methods in `ViewPager`.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
```

And to enable, just return each `super` method:

`super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)` and `super.onTouchEvent(event)`.

Answer (score 6):

For disabling swiping

```
mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
```

For enable swiping

`if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging()) 
     mViewPager.endFakeDrag();`

Comment: will have this issue https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/412

Comment: Can u pls elaborate your query?

Comment: I try to use this solution, but it'll throw NullPointerException when calling endFakeDrag.

Comment: try to use a condition like.
if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging()) mViewPager.endFakeDrag();

Comment: This doesn't stop swiping. It just makes it ugly

Answer (score 6):

If you want to extend it just because you need Not-Swipeable behaviour, you dont need to do it. ViewPager2 provides nice property called : `isUserInputEnabled`

Answer (score 5):

To disable swiping in viewpager2 use

```
viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

To enable swiping in viewpager2 Use

```
viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
```

Comment: viewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false // Disable swiping...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the simplified solution worked fine.
The override method must be in your custom viewpager adapter to override TouchEvent listeners and make'em freeze;

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.enabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);

}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.enabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Comment: provide an explanation about the solution provided

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC provided :)

Comment: With this solution thye views inside ViewPager will not receive any input if `this.enabled == false`. Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution that worked for me follow this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687397/4559365

It basically overrides the method `canScrollHorizontally` to disable swiping by finger. Howsoever `setCurrentItem` still works.

Comment: The `canScrollHorizontally()` method has no effect in current scenario. It is not even called when swipe happens.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
   ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // disable swipe
            if(!swipeEnabled) {
                if (viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()>1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            }
        }
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {}
    };
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
```