# Disable Tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I have used `TabLayout` from the latest design support library in my app. The tabs are attached to a viewpager which loads the fragments for each tab. I want to disable all the tabs until the viewpager loads the fragment for user selected tab. I am not able to disable the tablayout or make it non-clickable. I had used `setEnabled(false)` and `setClickable(false)` but it is not working. I am able to make it invisible by using `setVisiblity(View.GONE)` but I want the tabs to be visible at all times.

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.near_me_hover).setTag(1));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.all_hostels).setTag(2));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.top_five).setTag(3));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.advanced_search).setTag(4));
    tabLayout.setEnabled(false);
    tabLayout.setClickable(false);
```

**XML**

> android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>               android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
>               android:layout_width="match_parent"
>               android:layout_height="0dp"
>               android:layout_weight="0.15"
>               android:scrollbars="horizontal"
>               android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

```
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.near_me_hover);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.all_hostels_hover);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.top_five_hover);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.advanced_search_hover);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.near_me);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.all_hostels);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.top_five);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.advanced_search);

                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 3 methods implemented by the tab click listener, one of them is **onTabSelected() put a boolean condition to check if your fragment is initialised**. Then if that condition is satisfied then allow transaction to take place.
Also initialize the tabs after your fragment code

Comment: @war_hero, how to prevent tablayout from forwarding the touch to viewpager?

Comment: This is how you would disable it.            val tabStrip = reporting_tabs.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
            for (i in 0 until tabStrip.childCount) {
                tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
            }

Answer (score 3):

You can create a util function, my fun in Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun disableTabAt(tablayout: TabLayout?, index: Int) {
    (tablayout?.getChildAt(0) as? ViewGroup)?.getChildAt(index)?.isEnabled = false
}
```

When you want do something with a view, you can debug or click in parent view to know how it's created. By this way you can do anything that you want. For this case, you can go to Tablayout class to understand.

Comment: you should consider lowering the opacity of the disabled tab also, so it doesn't look like can still be selected; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64547361/2445763)

Answer (score 2):

Another trick:

You can put another blank transparent view upon tablayout until your requirement fulfill. When you need to enable/show the tabs then just hide the blank view.

Answer (score 2):

To enable specific tab at **position**  :

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));     
tabStrip.getChildAt(position).setOnTouchListener((v,event)->false);
```

To disable the tab at **position** :

```
 tabStrip.getChildAt(position).setOnTouchListener((v,event)->true);
```

Comment: Why? can you show the code? what is your requirement?

Comment: I means it only disable the touch event user can still go by scrolling view pager. so it's not perfect annwer in case userpager is scrollable.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong question, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442216/how-to-disable-or-enable-viewpager-swiping-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Here's 2 helper functions (kotlin) for disabling and enabling a TabItem by passing its name.

Tested using `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02`

```kotlin
fun disableTabItemAt(tabLayout: TabLayout?, tabText: String) {
    (tabLayout?.getChildAt(0) as? ViewGroup)?.children?.iterator()?.forEach {
            if((it as TabLayout.TabView).tab?.text == tabText) {
                it.isEnabled = false
                it.alpha = 0.5f
            }
    }
}

fun enableTabItemAt(tabLayout: TabLayout?, tabText: String) {
    (tabLayout?.getChildAt(0) as? ViewGroup)?.children?.iterator()?.forEach {
        if((it as TabLayout.TabView).tab?.text == tabText) {
            it.isEnabled = true
            it.alpha = 1f
        }
    }
}
```

So if your tab names are fixed, then you could do

```kotlin
disableTabItemAt(tabLayout, "Tab1")

// later enable it

enableTabItemAt(tabLayout, "Tab1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable tab, you just need use a customView

First at all, create your custom layout (textView as an example)

v_tabview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabItemView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:textColor="@drawable/selector_tab" />
```

create selector, for changing state enable/disable (changing color)

selector_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#9e9e9e" android:state_enabled="false" /> //gray
  <item android:color="#64b246" android:state_enabled="true" /> //green
</selector>
```

then inflate it, set names and add to the tabLayout

```
arrayStringNames.forEach { name ->
    val textView: TextView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.v_tabview, tabLayout, false) as TextView
    textView.text = name
    val tab = tabLayout.newTab()
    tab.customView = textView
    tabLayout.addTab(tab)
}
```

and at the end, a magic trick! In that sample code I disabling all tabs. If you need disable second and third tab, check "index" in a cycle and disable if you need

```
 for (index in 0 until tabLayout.tabCount) {
   ((tabLayout.getTabAt(index)?.customView) as? TextView)?.let { textView ->
     textView.isEnabled = enable //boolean
     (textView.parent as View).enable(enable)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best solution is to create a child of `TabLayout` that disables the touch interaction when using `setEnabled(false)`.
(note the below is Kotlin)

```kotlin
class NonTouchableTabLayout(context: Context,attributeSet: AttributeSet) : TabLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return !isEnabled
    }
}
```

This way you also get the UI changes of setting it disabled and you avoid relying on the inner workings of TabLayout (which may change) like some of the other answers suggest.

Answer (score -4):

If you mean to disable one tab button on TabLayout, then try this code:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(your_index).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Isn't tabhost different from the tablayout that i had used?

Comment: You can try if having any Issue then let me know i will check it out.

Comment: I think tabhost and tablayout from the design support library are entirely different. So i cant use this method.

Comment: LEt me check that Again.