# Android: Temporarily disable the ScreenSlide function

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slider

I am a beginner to programming and currently a bit lost.

I implemented a swipe function into my app by following a tutorial. It allows the user to slide between 2 Fragments by setting up a `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` class.

The following code is related to that `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incentive_timer);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                timerWindowReference = (TimerWindow) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                incentiveWindowReference = (SettingsWindow) createdFragment;
                break;
        }
        return createdFragment;
    }
}
```

My question:
I have a button and an `onClick` method. How can i disable and reenable this Slider functionality in there?

Comment: Did you want to disable and reenable the `Fragment` 's slide with `ViewPager`? I saw you use it.

Comment: Consider the given links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442216/how-to-disable-or-enable-viewpager-swiping-in-android                                                                                            
                                          
                                         http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/09/disable-swiping-on-viewpager-android.html

Comment: @KeLiuyue right!

Comment: @Tehmina Thank you, that link worked and it was much easier than i thought. I guess it was just too late for me yesterday.