# Want to avoid navigation on selection of TAB click

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to avoid loading of fragment on tab selection.

I have tablayout, I am on TAB1, but I want to navigate to TAB2 only if some specific condition got true else keep me on TAB1.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442216/how-to-disable-or-enable-viewpager-swiping-in-android