# ACTION_CANCEL is not working with non swipe ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My app have a ViewPager, and I don't want to allow user to swipe between pages and I use this as my ViewPager:

```
public class ViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {

    public ViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I don't know why after use this ViewPager, my `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` is not working anymore and how to fix it.
Please tell me why and give me some solutions about this.
Thanks.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442216/how-to-disable-or-enable-viewpager-swiping-in-android/40031147