# How to make swipe disable in a view pager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am creating an application contains of view pager with swipe-able tabs i want to do some operations inside view pager and at the time of operations i want to  disable the swipe view after operations done enable the swipe view 
can any one tell me how to do this and my activity was extending to the fragment activity thanks in advance

Comment: You've asked the same question just 2 hours ago!

Comment: Yes dude here i am using fragment activity that's my main problem @Hans1984

Comment: So why do you ask it again??? This is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: It's still very similar. Well, I'll let the mods take care of.

Comment: I have found a great solution that worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/42687397/4559365

Answer (score 41):

Create a new class which named `CustomViewPager`. The class inherits from `ViewPager` and includes a new method called `setPagingEnabled`. To enable / disable the swiping, just overwrite two methods: `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Both return false if the paging is disabled.

Here is the full code:

```
package com.yourpackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
}
```

Then in your layout.xml file replace any `<com.android.support.V4.ViewPager>` tags with `<com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager>` tags like below.

```
<com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager 
android:id="@+id/photosViewPager" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Now use `CustomViewPager` instead of `ViewPager` in your activity.
And that's it. Now, anytime to disable the swiping, just need to call the `setPagingEnabled` method with **false**.

```
CustomViewPager mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Here i am using the activity extends Fragment activity but here t was using the view pager.Can i do this in Fragment activity @Priyank

Comment: yes you can do it @lakshman.

Comment: I didn't get any overridden methods for fragment activity can u help me please @Priyank

Comment: Sorry dude i didn't see that i checking now @Chandrakanth

Comment: You need to create new class called `CustomViewPager` & use that `CustomViewPager` in your fragment activity & xml file instead of `ViewPager`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Basically its better to extend and then manage the code in a separate class then to do the dirty work in the Activity. Good Thanks!

Comment: one more function need to override to completely disable swiping onInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: This works perfect, and easy to grab .. Thanks @Priyank Patel

Comment: Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will prevent child views to receive input. In most cases this is __not__ the intended behavior.

Comment: @PriyankPatel How you achieve it? I have the same problem. I have to disable specific area of my 1st fragment. In my view pager I have total 5 fragment.

Answer (score -5):

**Try below methods**

To disable swiping call

```
viewPager.beginFakeDrag();
```

To enable swiping call

```
viewPager.endFakeDrag();
```

Comment: Shall i pass any Boolean value inside it @Chandrakanth

Comment: App was freezing dude with that method @Chandrakanth

Comment: How does this disable paging?