# android: How to disable scrolling on the viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, swipe

In my android application, I have a viewpager which have a list of imageView. Each of the view can be drawn. When I draw on it, I can still swipe to the next view from viewpager. How can I disable the paging while user start to draw on a an imageView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/3790150

Answer (score 6):

Add this as a class and use it in xml instead of your viewpager tag. Basically we make a customised viewpager, where we are disabling the swipeable behaviour by returning false to onInterceptTouchEvent and OnTouchEvent.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it work but I wanted to swipe the page in certain condition. There I placed an if statement in those two event function and return true but it doesn't work