# Prevent paging/swiping in cascaded ViewPager while handle scrolling of contained RecyclerView:

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, touch-event, android-touch-event

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 `Fragments` contained in it. One of the `Fragments` contains another `ViewPager`. which makes it a cascaded `ViewPager` inside a `ViewPager`.

I need to prevent the inner `ViewPager` from **swiping/paging** while allow it to pass the **scroll** gestures to the contained `RecyclerView`.

Yes I'm well aware that a `ViewPager` inside a `ViewPager` is not a great idea, yet in this case the view pager should no swipe but pass the gestures down to the child views. So there should not be a problem of two swipe mechanism in the same directions.

I tried to use the following `NonSwipeableViewPager` code for the inner view pager:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

  public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this indeed stops the `ViewPager` from **paging/swiping** but also prevents it from passing the touch events down to the `RecyclerView`.

How can I change this `ViewPager` to consume the **swiping/paging** gesture yet pass the **scrolling** gesture to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I won't help you in your issue, but just tell, that ViewPager in ViewPager is bad idea - try to change your design. (It is the same story as making scrollview with horizontal recyclerview inside)

Comment: You right in most cases, but in this case, where I don't wan't the inner view pager to be swappable, it's shouldn't be a problem. so it's basically a fragment container that give me a nice swiping animation when I press a tab, but does not change page by swiping

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/7118110