# Android: ViewPager swipe only on particular View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager`. Inside this ViewPager I have `Fragments` that have all the same layout. The layout contains a header and a `RecyclerView` and I want only the header of this layout to be swipeable. So the user may only switch between the fragments inside the viewpager when he is swipping on the header. I have tried a CustomViewPager but it was not working the way I wanted it to.

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: did you refer this ?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/3872374

Comment: @OmarDanisha Yes. Two problems that I have: On the first touch on the header, where i set swipeEnabled to true, the viewpager does not swipe. So I have to swipe twice. Second problem: Where do I set swipeEnabled to false when I touch a view that is not the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dirty but working solution is to set a custom `TouchListener` to my header view and every time it detects a fling to the right or left I call `setCurrentItem(index, true)` with the `ViewPager`. It is not the optimal solution, but is working for now.