# How to select next tab from child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I need to switch next tab, when a button is clicked from a child fragment.

This is how I setup tabs in parent,

```
TabAdapter adapter;

private void setUpTabs(ViewPager viewPager) {

    adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirstTabFragment(), "First Tab");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondTabFragment(), "Second Tab");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And my `TabAdapter` class is,

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

I created a method to switch tab inside Parent

```
TabLayout myTabs= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tabs);

Button chkBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_button);

chkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
});
```

Switching tabs inside parent class works fine. But how could I Do the same inside `FirstTabFragment`, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make your UI more Interactive and good looking, I'm gonna share what I've implemented.

Just to access your `viewPager` from the fragment's java file, declare your `viewPager` as below in your parent activity.

```
public static ViewPager viewPager;
```

Then in the `onClick` method or `onClickListener` of a button in the fragment, you can just use this.

```
ParentActivity.viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

This will smooth scroll your `viewpager` to the Second Fragment, and yes, if you want to limit the user from scrolling directly you can disable the scrolling of viewPager, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/8244632).

You can also shift the focus to left if user wants to go back to `FirstFragment` by just

```
ParentActivity.viewPager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT);
```

And yes, it's working as I first test before posting answers, silly me.

Answer (score 2):

you should use [**`setCurrentItem(int item)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean))

> Set the currently selected page. `

**sample code**

```
chkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me. I made an edit in question. can u please help on that

Answer (score 2):

You should call

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentIdex);`