# View Pager with OnLongClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onlongclicklistener

I have a `ViewPager` on which I am trying to apply `onLongClickListener` to change a Fragment from Activity which does not work.

```
mPager1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
     onViewPagerClick();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Fragment replacement:

```
 public void onViewPagerClick() {
     FragmentTransaction ft5 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     fragment = new SingleProductFragment();
     container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     ft5.add(R.id.container, fragment);
     // ft.addToBackStack(null);
     ft5.commit();
     sv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     addButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: please you can write more code

Comment: I have placed the code in my Activity class within onCreate

Comment: Have you tried [such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707510/8244632) answers?

Comment: the scrolling already shows the next images using ArrayAdapter.I want apply a onLongClick which opens another fragment to display the details of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager doesn't consume click events so try to set the listener on your image or container layout instead of viewPager in `instantiateItem()`.

***UPDATE***

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
ViewGroup viewPagerItem = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewPager_item, container, false);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)viewPagerItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
viewPagerItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
     }
    });

  container.addView(viewPagerItem);

  return viewPagerItem;
}
```

Comment: i tried it on the container as it is within a elative layout but it doesnt work either

Comment: If you tried `container` variable from the `instantiateItem` method that variable is the viewPager. In my suggestion I meant the container layout in which is your imageView. I updated the answer with an example. It should work this way :)

Comment: I want to replace a fragment but when I am using getFragmentManager() method within view pager adapter android studio doesnt recognize that method