# Open particular tab on click of imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-tablayout

I have used multiple tab layout activities (ex.5) & multiple image view (ex:5 ).i click (Ex:3) image then open particular tab  (Ex:3). how to write code anybody help.Image used in main activity image click enter tab layout particular tab.

Comment: **[viewPager.setCurrentItem(position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean))**

Comment: any examples codes???

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46705195/7666442

Answer (score 0):

Use Android TabHost and its method setCurrentTab() in your onCreate()-method.Pass your required tab index to this onCreate()

Comment: Not particular open tab activity. I want sliding tab then slide all tabs

Answer (score 0):

On using **ViewPager** pass the selected imageview position

```
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
```

Using TabLayout, add onTabSelectedListener to swipe views

```
  tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

When it comes to slide

```
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
        new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, 0f, true);
               }
        });
```