# View Pager scrollable false

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have viewPager with 2 fragments of user complete profile, what my problem is I dont want to let the user to swipe the second fragment of my view pager unless user completes the first profile fragment. My aim is user must fill the first profile fragment and click confirm button then my view pager will swipe the second fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable scrolling on a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/is-it-possible-to-disable-scrolling-on-a-viewpager)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/8089770

Comment: I just use Fragment pager adapter, plz can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use StepperView for your purpose. Kindly go through this library.
You can add a form validation on button on first page, if validation satisfies, then step into next step.
[Android Material Stepper](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5138)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/6549856 can create custom `ViewPager` which will disable swipe gestures and after it, you can make call to your second fragment as

```
btn_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
    }
});
```