# How to disable the scroll of parent view while scrolling the RecyclerView item?

Tags: java, android

I have a `ViewPager` inside  `Activity`. The  `ViewPager` is inside the `ScrollView`. In the fragment I have `RecyclerView`. When I scroll the recycler item I need to disable the activity scroll. How do I achieve that. I search on but nothing found. Please help me in it. I stuck for sometime in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent on view like bellow

```
yourviewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                recyclerview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
//or you can apply on ScrollView also
                //scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: vpChatType.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                my_scrolview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
//or you can apply on ScrollView also
                //scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Okay, let me try with your same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot disable the scrolling of a ScrollView. You would need to
>   extend to ScrollView and override the onTouchEvent method to return
>   false when some condition is matched.

More info here: [Disable ScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763304/disable-scrollview-programmatically)

More info about ViewPager: [Is it possible to disable scrolling on a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/is-it-possible-to-disable-scrolling-on-a-viewpager)

Comment: Actually i saw the link as you provided but the thing is inside  the scrollview i have viewpager. And recyclerview is inside the fragment. then how do i disable the activity scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag into your RecyclerView in XML layout

```
        android:overScrollMode="always"
```