# How can I have a fragment inside another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to build a fragment (Fragment0) with a TabLayout.
When I click on Tab1, I want to navigate to Fragment1.
When I click on Tab2, I want to navigate to Fragment2.
When I click on Tab3, I want to navigate to Fragment3.

I don't want to use a ViewPager.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewPager and disable the scrolling like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814054/10002974

Also, if you don't want to use that then you can try this:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```