# Disable Scroll left in ViewPager Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I know this is common to ask but still I'm confused how can I disable scroll to left from `ViewPager`, What I'm trying to do is when the `input field/household field` is empty you cannot procced to the next part, currently it works on the button when I'm trying to click next button it will pops `Toast`, but when I scroll using my finger it didn't work since I didn't applied it yet, can anyone explain or how can I achieve this? I'm struggling with this one.

[image]

**OnBoardingScreen - Java**

```
private TextView tvNext, tvSkip;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private LinearLayout layoutDots;
private IntroPref introPref;
private int[] layouts;
private TextView[] dots;
private MyViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

EditText edt_hh;

  tvNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt_hh = findViewById(R.id.edt_hh_no);
                household = edt_hh.getText().toString();

                int current = getItem(+1);
//
                if (household.matches("")){
                    Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Required", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (current < layouts.length) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                }

                else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });


ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);
        edt_hh = findViewById(R.id.edt_hh_no);
        household = edt_hh.getText().toString();

        if (household.matches("")){
            Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Required", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            tvNext.setText("SCAN");
        } else {
            tvNext.setText("NEXT");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
};

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
    int[] activeColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.active);
    int[] inActiveColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.inactive);
    layoutDots.removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(50);
        dots[i].setTextColor(inActiveColors[currentPage]);
        layoutDots.addView(dots[i]);
    }
    if (dots.length > 0) {
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(activeColors[currentPage]);
    }
}

public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    showImageImportDialog();
}

private void changeStatusBarColor() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to [enable-disable](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setUserInputEnabled(boolean)) swiping `viewpager2`
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2

Note: If your app already uses [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager), see [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration).

Sample code to disable swiping in viewpager2

```
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

Sample code to enable swiping in viewpager2

```
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I tried apply the source that you provided but it seems the `setUserInputEnabled` did not identified inside `ViewPager` please see the image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQ1C.png)

Comment: I tried apply the source that you provided

Comment: It seem that you still using ViewPager. Please follow the guideline  to change to [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your view pager scroll using custom `ViewPager` :

[Is it possible to disable scrolling on a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814017/is-it-possible-to-disable-scrolling-on-a-viewpager)

Comment: I tried that before but the design of my xml will error please see the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvDo.png)

Comment: It does not matter weather it is showing or not in layout, you need to run the app.